# Combinations with replacement Java

Tags: java, replace, permutation

For the last couple of days, I am trying to solve this problem of combinations with replacement in java. I checked other languages as well maybe it was done in them and I could translate to java but with no luck, so any help greatly appreciated.

So here is the problem(mock interview question) I came upon:

Combine from range 0 - 6(n)
In an array of size r (let's say 3)

So the formula for combinations with replacement is C(n,r)=(n+r−1)! / r!(n−1)!. In this case the combinations will be 84

```
000
010,
011,
...,
025,
055,
...,
666.
```

However, I can't get my head around this algorithm WITH REPLACEMENT which is an entirely different story from without replacement.

Thank you again in advance for your help.

Comment: Hello Eileen - what is your question?

Comment: what you mean by "WITH REPLACEMENT"?

Comment: @ScaryWombat well If anyone help me figure the algorithm either by code example or pseudocode. Nawnit Sen it means that repetitions are allowed

Comment: Not sure why the combinations will be `84` Assuming the output is chars in length, the first char can be 0-6, the second also 0-6 and finally the last char can be 0-6 hence 6*6*6 = 214 - or am I totally misunderstanding you

Comment: @ScaryWombat actually it should be 7*7*7 including 6.@Ellen why your o/p starts from 010 instaed of 000?

Comment: @NawnitSen I can't even count

Comment: @NawnitSen I still do not understand the answer to the question you asked - what is *with replacement*

Comment: @ScaryWombat it means repeatation of digit is allowed in three digits .for ex- 000 or 010 is allowed, here 0 is repeating.

Comment: @NawnitSen Oh OK.

Comment: He means the set that is described by the so-called Multiset coefficient of the multinomial theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieved first version of answer:

You can use `nn=(n+1)` variants of digit at every of `r` places, so overall number of combinations is `P = nn^r`. Note that every combination corresponds to the number in range `0..P-1`.

So you can walk through all integer values in range `0..P-1` and represent loop counter in nn-ary system.

[Java code](https://ideone.com/neQ3G0)

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int n = 2;
    int r = 3;
    int nn = n + 1;
    int p = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
      p *= nn;
    for (int i=0; i<p; i++){
        int t = i;
        String comb = "(";
        for (int j=0; j<r; j++){
            comb = comb + String.format("%2d, ", t % nn);
            t = t / nn;
        }
        comb = comb.substring(0, comb.length()-2) + ')';
        System.out.println(comb);
    }
}
```

Python code:

```
n = 2
r = 3
nn = n + 1
p = nn**r
for V in range(p):
    t = V
    comb = []
    for i in range(r):
        d = t % nn
        comb.append(d)
        t = t // nn
    print(comb)

[0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 0]
[0, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1]
[0, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
```

The second version: for combinations with replacement.
Recursive (the simplest way) generation in Python.

```
def cwrreq(maxlen, maxx, s):
    if len(s)== maxlen:
        print(s)
    else:
        for i in range(maxx + 1):
            cwrreq(maxlen, i, s + str(i))

def combwithrepl(maxlen, maxval):
    cwrreq(maxlen, maxval, "")

combwithrepl(3, 6)
```

generates 84 combinations

```
000
100
110
111
200
...
663
664
665
666
```

Full list for (3,3).
Meaning: there are three indistinguishable boxes and three kinds of paints (say red, green, blue).

```
000    all boxes are hollow
100    one box is red
110
111    all boxes are red
200
210    one box is green,  another is red
211
220
221
222
300
310
311
320
321   all boxes have distinct colors
322
330
331
332
333   all boxes are blue
```

Comment: Hello although I appreciate the attempt, the question has been edited to combinations with replacement.

Comment: OK, I was disoriented by `010` combination and decided that it is just arbitrary example. Replaced with code for combinations with replacement

Comment: To be honest, I am a bit confused at this point. the example wants 000,010,011,016 as well as 661 that's combinations not permutation right? Will your current algorithm produce this? Also could you please edit it with some comments, python is not my strongest language, thank you in advance @Mbo

Comment: Why 010? What's a strange choice? You haven't specified needed order clearly, so I generated **colex** ordering as the simplest. Note that any "permutation of 001": 001 010 100 - is really the same combination - multiset of two zeros and a one. In any case code generates all needed combinations

Comment: Because the range of numbers I am combining will be replaced with letters so 010,001 and 100 all mean a different word. SO does 661,616 or 166. Thats the end game of the algorithm really

Comment: So combinatorial structure you want to get - is not "combinations with replacement" because combinations don't account for items order. You can edit the question and show full list you want for 3,3

Comment: So you are saying I am trying to do permutations then?

Comment: I just doubt what you really need. If you want both 001 and 010 and 100 - all these variants were in the my first answer with (n+1)^r outputs. I've added explanation of output for current code.

Comment: Oh must have missed that because i was fixated on combination with replacement. Any chance you can post that also underneath that code so people can benefit from both and i can just accept the answer? So we cant name what i need the example of the outout should be 116,161 as well as 611 etc for all other combinations obviously

Comment: Ok i will implement it in java and let you know by accepting the answer if correct

Comment: Java version https://ideone.com/fhD0YG (I don't know how to properly pack digits in string, so collect them in integer)

Comment: I tried this with n = 21  and r = 3 and I get this 
1901
2001
2101
2201
2301
211
311
411
511
611
711
811
911
1011
 so sometimes for some reason it puts 4 numbers together and other times it puts 3, sometimes i even get 2 digits or even 1

Comment: Make better output, collect integers into string with delimiters like "19, 0, 1" - I don't know Java enough to propose good output method. Perhaps your 1901 = 19 + 0 + 1

Comment: I made Java code with better formatted output and put it in answer

Comment: I have changed your code to my needs but at least I must thank you for the algorithm. I have accepted and upvoted you, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static List<int[]> samples(int n, int k) {
    if (k < 0 || n < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (k == 0) return Collections.emptyList();

    List<Integer> set = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) set.add(i);
    if (k == 1) return set.stream().map(i -> new int[]{i}).collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<int[]> previous = samples(n, k - 1);
    List<int[]> out = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i : set) for (int[] array : previous) out.add(glue(i, array));

    return out;
}

private static int[] glue(int i, int[] array) {
    int[] out = new int[array.length + 1];
    out[0] = i;
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, out, 1, array.length);
    return out;
}
```

e.g.,

```
for (int[] sample : samples(2, 3)) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sample));
}
```

yields

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
```

and

```
for (int[] sample : samples(4, 2)) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sample));
}
```

yields

```
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[0, 3]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 0]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 0]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
```